# Go test coverage, if statement not covered

Tags: go, go-testing

I have a go function called setupConfig() and I have a Test_setupconfig that tests it and tests it just fine.  But when I do a cover test on it and look at the HTML report, it shows my handling of some error returns by the Viper package is not covered.  Why is this not covered and how do I handle this?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: Those are not covered, because your test did not execute those branches.

Comment: It's not covered because none of your test cases cause `viper` to error.  While the code in question is trivial, it is nice to see full coverage.  In that case you'll have to extract the failable commands into a separate function so you can feed in erroneous configs to cause an error.

Comment: @Volker I uploaded an image so the format of the HTML can be seen in the report itself.  Just posting text would not show the format of the report.

Comment: @erik258 Im not sure I understand what you mean by "extract the failable commands into a separate function so you can feed in erroneous configs to cause an error".  Do you mean I need a separate test function that calls "viper.BindPFlags()" and look for a way to make it fail just so the coverage considers this covered?

Comment: Why is it important for you to ensure that `return err` is covered? There is no logic there which could be wrong, and if you have sufficient coverage in the caller, these lines are irrelevant.

Comment: @JimB I agree they are irrelevant, and i can just ignore that part of the reports, but i wanted to know why it thinks it is uncovered when it is a return from an imported package and I am handling the error.  This decreases my test coverage percentage report, and even though I am comfortable with how I am handling it, it would be good to have it seen as covered.

Comment: Test "coverage" means that the lines have actually been _executed_ by a test, these have not been executed.

Comment: @JimB So you mean, the tests I have written never reach those lines of code, and I would have to devise a way to create a test where it would reach those lines of code to be considered completely covered. Correct?

Comment: yes, that is what test coverage means

Comment: @JimB Thanks for explaining.  I thoroughly get it now.  I just didnt get that one part and I appreciate you explaining it to me.

Comment: @Volker The image I posted is the HTML page that is the output of doing a go test coverage report.  Its not straight text, but an HTML report which shows the details of the report.  For future reference, since you commented I should not post images of text, how should I post the output of an HTML report when that is the subject of the post?  Just so I know how to do it in the future and not get downvoted for it?

Comment: We do know how HTML cover reports look like. You could have posted a code snippet with a comment `//  <--- why not covered ??`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage report tells you how much of your code is executed during tests. What you're seeing is the `return` statements within those `if` blocks are not tested, which means you don't have any unit tests that are designed to fail and return errors. While testing that you code works when given correct input, it's also important to ensure that tests fail correctly and safely when given bad input.

However, this is a weird situation because those errors aren't within your own package, those errors are coming from the `viper` package. at this point it's important to ask yourself the question "what am I really testing?". If you're using the `viper` package then the assumption is that package is thoroughly tested, and by creating your own tests for the viper errors you're just doubling up on those tests with no real improvements. For this reason, sometimes we choose to omit testing these branches because realistically, if the viper package errors - and assuming all your inputs are static and hard coded like shown - then that's not a problem with your code that's a problem with the `viper` library.

If you *really* want to get 100% coverage and test all decision trees, the only way to do so is to put the `viper` package behind some kind of abstraction. Most likely an interface that's passed into the function allowing for multiple implementations whether you're running in production or running in tests.

With that said, hard coding all your values within the function like that isn't recommended practice. Ideally you'd want the values of your config struct coming from a local config file, environment variables, commandline flags, or a combination of them. By doing this, you could have this setup function accept an interface that it uses to retrieve the configuration, making this function easily testable as all you'd need to do is mock out the implementation of that interface in your tests. So it would be something like the following:

`config.go`:

```golang
type ConfigController interface {
    GetInput() Config
}

func setupConfig(controller ConfigController) error {
    config := controller.GetInput()
    // your code here
}
```

`config_test.go`:

```golang
type mockConfigController struct {}

func (m *mockConfigController) GetConfig() Config {
    return Config{
        // your config here
    }
}

func Test_setupConfig(t *testing.T) {
    configController := &mockConfigController{}
    err := setupConfig(configController)
    // rest of test here
}
```

By doing this and giving your `setupConfig()` function accepting an interface, it means you can give it a function implementation when it's running in production, but also mock it out with hard-coded test data when running tests. This is quite often used when interacting with other services too, like databases. Instead of having to spin up a database and connect to it when running tests, you can have your code accept an interface that tells it how to interact with the database and mock it out in tests. This allows you to isolate parts of your code and only test exactly what you're wanting to.

Comment: Those hard coded values within that function are the default values for the Config struct.  In the command ```viper.ReadInConfig``` actually does read in from a config file and if defined overrides the default values.  Since I am using viper as the config controller, it really wouldnt be worth mocking it up just to cover those return values.  It would be nice to have some way to tell coverage test to ignore those branches, but alas Ive chosen to just accept it and not have 100% coverage report.  Thanks for your detailed answer though, it was spot on.

Comment: @DanSherwin Ah okay, makes sense about the viper library. Yeah I run into a lot of cases like this where you're getting errors from packages and I also normally just don't test that route. If the package errors then that's their problem haha